# Machine learning models with same accuracy metrics but different visualization of predicted vs test

Tags: validation, machine-learning, keras, visualization, random-forest

I am comparing a random forest (RF) with a feed-forward neural network (NN) to predict species richness. In both models, I used the same (60) predictors. The issue is that the r2 and root mean squared errors are very similar, but when I plot predicted vs test, the NN looks much much better. Is that so? or is it just a perception issue?
These are  the results for the NN:

```
RMSE: 7 ±0.5
Relative RMSE: 0.26 ±0.04
r2: 0.36 ±0.1
```

[Predicted vs test NN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfsJ7.png)

And for RF:

```
RMSE: 7 ±1.1
Relative RMSE: 0.25 ±0.06
r2: 0.36 ±0.1
```

[Predicted vs test RF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkM0y.png)

The results are an average for the 5 folds, and the plots show all the accumulated predictions of the 5 folds vs the true values. Both models were built in python (keras for NN and sklearn for RF).

To wrap it up, if I trust the numbers, both models perform the same, but NN has the best fit visually. Is there another validation metric that could tell which model performs better?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Wouldn't this fit into how to implement a solution (to determine if there is a difference between models)? The answer from Nir was already very helpful. I'm now trying to get familiar with deepchecks.

Comment: Sorry, no; the answer below is indeed helpful because it advises on *methodology*, and it is still not about programming (as is the question itself). Being "helpful" in general is not a sufficient criterion in itself - it must be helpful *and on-topic*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a better look on the distribution of the error, rather than just the raw mean and std.

This all depends on your target - what is the cost of a mistake? if your model tends to be accurate but has a small percentage of being **completely** wrong, is that ok, or would you prefer a more stable model but with higher error margins?

For example, you can use this code to check your MSE distribution (disclaimer: I'm one of the maintainers of the used [package](https://docs.deepchecks.com/en/)):

```
from deepchecks.checks import RegressionErrorDistribution
RegressionErrorDistribution().run(test_data, model)
```

Another  more advanced option is to use look at the error analysis, which shows you how predictible your error is, meaning in which segments of your data your model tends to be more wrong. This too can help you decide which model is better, depending on the segments of data which are more important to you:

```
from deepchecks.checks import ModelErrorAnalysis
ModelErrorAnalysis(min_error_model_score=0.3).run(train_data, test_data, model)
```

[image: Example of ModelErrorAnalysis result]